# Google Sheets Lookup Row and Get Last Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with two sheets in it.

The first sheet is a list of songs with Title, Library #, Composer, ..., Last Performance Date
The second sheet is a list of performance dates with Title, Library #, date 1, date 2, ..., date n

**Sheet 1 Example**:

```
Title,     Library #,    Composer,    Last Performance Date
Hip Song   1007          David        {formula}
Slow Song  1002          Bob          {formula}
Other Song 1004          David        {formula}
```

**Sheet 2 Example**:

```
Title,     Library #,    Dates ->
Slow Song  1002          2021-01-12    2021-02-15
Other Song 1004          
Hip Song   1007          2021-01-05
```

How can I automatically fill in the "Last Performance Date" column on the first sheet by looking up the song on the second sheet by the "Library #" and getting the last value in that row (with a variable number of dates per song on the second sheet).

With the example above, the Last Performance Date for "Hip Song" would be "2021-01-05", "Slow Song" would be "2021-02-15", and "Other Song" would be "" (an empty string or nothing).
For any given song, there could be no dates on the second sheet or a 100+ dates on that song's row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a helper column to Sheet2 that contains the formula that calculates the "latest" date for a given song:

**Sheet2**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Title** | **Library #** | **Latest Date** | **Dates** |  |
| 2 | Slow Song | 1002 | =IF(MAX(D2:E2)=0,"",MAX(D2:E2)) | 2021-01-12 | 2021-02-15 |
| 3 | Other Song | 1004 | =IF(MAX(D3:E3)=0,"",MAX(D3:E3)) |  |  |
| 4 | Hip Song | 1007 | =IF(MAX(D4:E4)=0,"",MAX(D4:E4)) | 2021-01-05 |  |

The `IF(X=0,"",X)` part of the formula is so that songs that don't have any dates show up as blank instead of 0 (which will get formatted as `1899-12-30`).

Then, in `Sheet1`, use the `VLOOKUP` function to find the matching "latest date":

**Sheet1**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Title** | **Library #** | **Composer** | **Last Performance Date** |
| 2 | Hip Song | 1007 | David | =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE) |
| 3 | Slow Song | 1002 | Bob | =VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE) |
| 4 | Other Song | 1004 | David | =VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE) |

Note the `FALSE` as the last parameter to `VLOOKUP`, which makes sure it will still return correct results, even if the data in `Sheet2` is not sorted by `Library #`.

See [this example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1lhHCHYq6K2RYw9f6XqNE-Q381RvkH-aGz3av73ElY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I like having the convenience lookup of the last date on Sheet2 in case the dates end up going off the end of the screen.
I did modify the formulas so that they were boundless, and everything is working great.
`=IF(MAX(D2:2)=0,"",MAX(D2:2))` and `=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!$B$2:$C, 2, False)`

Answer (score 1):

if your dates (if present) are increasing with each next column try:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,IFERROR(1*SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!B1:1000, 
 TRANSPOSE(SORT(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Sheet2!C1:1))+1, 1, 0))), 0)),,9^9)), " "))),,1)
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJRwOwNDQ6jZtpNPn5yTpHfn1SB3XFA1r7C8Tv92eiI/edit#gid=0)

**fx transcript:** count columns from column with 1st date and create a sequence of number with +1 offset for each number. then sort the sequence in descending order and transpose it into row - this will be the 3rd parameter of vlookup which will return date columns in reverse order eg.: ..., Col5, Col4, Col3, Col2. so in vlookup we look for B2:B values in range Sheet2:B1:1000 and return multiple columns on each match. next, we transpose all results of vlookup and with query parameter `,,9^9` we collapse all rows of each column into a single row. next, we flatten the results and split by empty space (which was inserted after each date via query). in this stage, column with the latest date became our 1st column. next, dates are numeric values so we multiply them by 1 to catch errors of those cells that have no date only empty spaces. at last, we use simple if statement to check if B2:B range is empty. if so we return no value, otherwise we return date. and to limit the output only to 1 single column we use index to return all rows but only the first column

Comment: This does work when Sheet 2 is ordered by Library # which would be the ideal case, but I know a user will probably sort the sheet by Title at some point.

I'm leaning towards Andrew's answer because I like having the quick lookup of the most recent performance date on Sheet 2 as well (in case the dates go off the end of the screen).

Comment: @BryanHurst could be moded to work with any order if you wish